# CPU fan twitching phase leds blinking - computer won't boot

Tags: power-supply, led, flashing

I have a big problem that I got today.

Yesterday computer was "on" normally, I went to sleep without shutting it down. When I woke up, I heard a strange sound and was unable to bring it up from hibernate. I unplugged the PSU.

When I plugged the PSU back in, the sound came back. When I opened the case, I saw the fan "twitching" like it is about to start and fan LEDs were blinking. Also, motherboard LEDs were blinking in the same pattern - the first green one has more of luminosity then others.

When I cut down the power with 0/1 button on PSU, the fans continue to make sounds like the machine is trying to boot before the capacitors run out and the power dies.

Does anyone have a clue what to do? I tried disassembling everything but that doesn't work. I will try with friend's PSU later today.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you either have a fried power supply, or a short circuiting motherboard.

Try it with your friend's power supply, and if it boots normally then you have a bad PSU that will need to be replaced.

If your friend's power supply wont boot it, then the motherboard is shorting out and you will need to replace THAT... though if that is the case you may as well chuck the computer entirely and get a new one, since its not all that cost-effective to repair something like that.